# Querying MYSQL post_meta to new format of table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, metadata

Hi I have a existing table which is

post_meta

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| meta_id  | post_id      | meta_key   | meta_value            |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  1       | 1            | field1     | John Doe              |
|  2       | 1            | field2     | jonedoe@gmail.com     |
|  3       | 1            | field3     | 099999999             |
|  4       | 2            | field1     | Err ManMa             |
|  5       | 2            | field2     | errmanma@gmail.com    |
|  6       | 2            | field3     | 09231412312           |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I create or format my post_meta table like this?

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
| meta_id  | field1    | field2             | field3            |
----------------------------------------------------------------
|  1       | John Doe  | jonedoe@gmail.com  | 099999999         |
|  2       | Err ManMa | errmanma@gmail.com | 09231412312       |
----------------------------------------------------------------
```

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your result columns should be `post_id, field1, field2, field3` and then this is a table pivot issue, try this:

```
select
    post_id,
    max(case when meta_key = 'field1' then meta_value end) as field1,
    max(case when meta_key = 'field2' then meta_value end) as field2,
    max(case when meta_key = 'field3' then meta_value end) as field3
from post_meta
-- where meta_key in ('field1', 'field2', 'field3')
group by post_id
-- having coalesce(field1, field2, field3) is not null
```

### SQLFiddle Demo

.

Comment: Great! Code working fine but my query contains a NULL value how can I exclude all NULL values?

Comment: @CarlvicJapitanaLim Do you mean about `field1, field2, field3` has `null` values?

Comment: Yes because I have other post_id don't have meta_key field1, field2, and field3

Comment: @CarlvicJapitanaLim If any of these three columns is null value then exclude it, do you mean this?

Comment: hmmm. I mean we use groupby to post_id right? Since we groupby a post_id I have post_id don't have a field1,field2 and field3. So how can i exclude post_id dn't have a field1,field2 and field3 column.

Comment: Got it ! Great help!

Comment: Can I have another question?

Comment: Of course you can, but I think you should ask a new question on SO. :-)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/117310/discussion-between-carlvic-japitana-lim-and-10086).